# How to replicate a directory structure using xcopy in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, xcopy

I have a text file containing a list of folders.My text file looks like this:

```
"D:\old\FOLDER1"  
"D:\old\FOLDER2"  
"D:\old\FOLDER3"  
"D:\old\FOLDER4"  
"D:\old\FOLDER5"
```

all these folders have subfolders and files under it

what I want to do is use xcopy to copy `FOLDER1`, `FOLDER2` , `FOLDER3` `FOLDER4` and `FOLDER5` replicate folders ,replicating the structure of those folders
so in output , I want to get

```
D:\output\bkup\FOLDER1\............Including all subfolders and files D:\output\bkup\FOLDER2\............Including all subfolders and files D:\output\bkup\FOLDER3\.......... Including all subfolders and files 
D:\output\bkup\FOLDER4\............Including all subfolders and files 
D:\output\bkup\FOLDER5\............ Including all subfolders and files
```

I have written  below script which works fine for one folder

```
set sourceFolder="D:\old\FOLDER5"
set destinationFolder=%sourceFolder:~7,-1%
echo %destinationFolder%
xcopy /s /e /i /h /r /y %sourceFolder%  "D:\output\bkup%destinationFolder%"
```

but since # of directories to copy is 100+ ,I like to use a for loop or pass the list of directories to copy in a text file , that's what I don't know how to handle it.

please help me ,I'm not expert in batch file writing.

Comment: @rene
thanks for your time, I get an error 'docopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: made an edit and added support for a text file `"My File With Source Folders.txt"` and `xcopy`.

Comment: @user2434611 fixed a bug in my answer by adding a colon

Comment: @rene thank you very much for helping me out, your code works perfct for my need

Comment: @rene in practice, my directory name is long, each line in text file is like this "F:\SCRIPTS\00\48\64\06\BAT140_PLM_PRIM_Feature line Proposals table - edit"   so after process generated sourceFolder is; "BAT140_PLM_PRIM_Feature" instead of "BAT140_PLM_PRIM_Feature line Proposals table - edit" ,part of the path is chopped off , any idea

Comment: @user2434611 fixed in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for /f to read (parse if needed) a textfile line by line. Use "delims=" to read the line as a whole. Don't forget to add quotes to prevent having multiple arguments and strip the quotes in the subprocedure

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (yourtextfile.txt) do call :docopy "%%a"
goto :eof

:docopy
set sourceFolder=%~1
set destinationFolder=%sourceFolder:~7,-1%
echo %destinationFolder%
xcopy /s /e /i /h /r /y %sourceFolder%  "D:\output\bkup%destinationFolder%" 
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2):

try `robocopy`, it is more powerfull for your needs, available for XP Prof. or newer:

```
set "sourceFolder=D:\old\FOLDER5"
set "destinationFolder=%sourceFolder:~7,-1%"
robocopy "%sourceFolder%" "%destinationFolder%" /MIR
```

This makes a complete MIRror at "%destinationFolder%".

If you want to copy folders from a text file with `xcopy`, use the following code:

```
set "sourceFolder=D:\old\FOLDER5"
set "destinationFolder=%sourceFolder:~7,-1%"
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("My File With Source Folders.txt") do xcopy /seihry "%%i" "D:\output\bkup%destinationFolder%"
```

Text file with source folders is `"My File With Source Folders.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the solution from this [Microsoft forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0b3d3006-0e0f-4c95-9e2f-4c820832ebfa/using-robocopy-to-copy-folder-structure-only?forum=w7itprogeneral) thread:

To copy folder structure of another without copying files.

Here "ProjectsX" folder is replaced into "ProjectsY" - within SVN directory

**/E** - include empty directories

**/XF *** - all files are excluded

**/XD ".svn" "obj"** - specified directories are excluded

```
D:\SVN>robocopy ProjectsX ProjectsY /E /XF * /XD ".svn" "obj"
```

Thanks to the hint to *robocopy* in the previous [answer by Endoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877810/5876282). But you don't need mirroring for this really.